Extension cadastre (QGIS/EDIGEO data)
I try to use cadastre extension 1.29.1 with QGIS LTR 3.34.6. I import EDIGEO data.
The vector data are displayed but without the toponym! so The map doesn't read:

cadastral plot number.
Street names.
Adress.
And so on!

Would you please give some answers to solve this issue?

I repost my previous comment as I think this still apply to the English version of the question : As your question refer to a third party french plugin you are more likely to get answer by directly going to the plugin page (docs.3liz.org/QgisCadastrePlugin and github.com/3liz/QgisCadastrePlugin/issues)
